# Encryption not working with every character

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt data (mostly textfiles and images) and it's working fine until some special characters occur (for example the degree character °). The decrypted file then has this  character � in it instead of the actual character.

Currently I'm using the Rijndael Cipher to encrypt files as shown on this website:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704372/How-to-Use-Rijndael-ManagedEncryption-with-Csharp

How would I go about changing it so every character (also those in an image when you open it with a text editor) will be correctly decrypted?

Also: Is this a good method to encrypt data, expecially images? If not, please point me in the right direction or link me to a post that explains it.

Comment: Images aren't made of *characters* - they're made of *bytes*. If you're dealing with characters at any point, you'll probably be losing data. But you haven't shown us what code you're using (beyond what's on the CodeProject page) so it's very hard to help you.

Comment: I'm using exactly the code that is on CodeProject. I wasn't sure If I should copy/paste the code into here.

Comment: Well you must be using more than that, because you've got to *call* those methods - and I suspect that's at least part of where the problem is. You're reading images as text - you must be, because those methods only deal with text - and images simply aren't text. I wouldn't use that code at all, to be honest...

Comment: Well yes, I'm using a streamreader to read an image as text. I've come across some ciphers for images that manipulate the bytes of it but they didn't work for me (probably because I used them wrong).
Do you have some examples for me that you would use?

Comment: Right, so don't do that. `StreamReader` is meant for reading text, and this isn't text. You can adapt the example you've got - just remove the bit that's converting the text to binary data. But there are hundreds - thousands - of examples of C# encryption on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently it's near impossible to say without the code snippet that you use. But my guess it that after you decrypt you transform it to string using the wrong encoding. So I would suggest that you:

1. Provide code snippet
2. Check that the bytes that are encrypted get decrypted to correct bytes (Encrypt/decrypt this one symbol which is probably a couple of bytes)
3. Verify that you have same encoding when you convert to bytes and back

Answer (score -1):

It would make the file larger but you might be able to convert the file to base64 encoding first which in turn should encrypted/decrypt properly. There of course is most likely a better solution but I've not come across your problem before.